# Can't use autogenerated Swift bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I am attempting to use the autogenerated Swift bridging header in an Objective-C class, but when I try to include it, I get many errors in the bridging header. Since the header is automatically generated, its not at all clear what I might have wrong.

In an Objective-C class, if I declare the following line I will get build errors - without this line, no errors and it builds fine:

```
#import "Oilist-Swift.h"
```

EDIT: I just moved the `#import "Oilist-Swift.h"` statement to after all the other headers have been imported, and now I only get errors relating to `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` and possibly one error relating to `PopupStoreControllerDelegate`. Here are all the errors now:

```
Angle brackets contain both a protocol ('PopupStoreControllerDelegate') and a type ('MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate')

Unknown class name 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate'; did you mean 'MFMailComposeViewController'?
Replace 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate' with 'MFMailComposeViewController'

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController * _Nonnull)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError * _Nullable)error;
  Expected a type (MFMailComposeResult)
```

I've looked for circular references and can't find any so far.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Seems really close now - it seems its just not happy with MFMail for some unknown reason.

Comment: It seems that your PopupStoreControllerDelegate cannot be used in objective-C. Did you use `@objc` in its declaration? And you also possibly need to add a forward `@protocol PopupStoreControllerDelegate;` in the header file.

Comment: Hmm - PopupStoreControllerDelegate is from an Objective-C class. What header file are you suggesting adding `@protocol` to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I import `MessageUI.h` it works now. (Despite MessageUI not being used at all in the class importing the Swift header).

I guess I have to import MessageUI because it is referenced in the bridging header and doesn't include a definition for the MessageUI stuff...

Solution:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import "Oilist-Swift.h"
```